# New Categories Not Shown In the Post Edit Page

Tags: categories, taxonomy, block-editor

I have a problem with setting up new categories for my new posts.

When I publish my second article on the blog, I have created e new category. But when I posted it, the actual category is not showing in the post.

Example.

Old Post with Category A

New Post with category B.

When I posted the new Post, the breadcrumbs show Category A, not category B. Category B does not appear on the post edit page (Gutenberg). But when I want to select the category for menus, it appears.

I tried to add another new category for the same post. But the result is the same. The new categories don’t show up in the Gutenberg right-hand site settings panel.

How to resolve this?

"I have disabled all the plugins, also switched to the default themes, and purged cache from Cloudflare as well. I rebuild permalink as well. But the results were the same. The new categories didn't show up in the post edit panel."

Thank you!

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins ant third-party themes, cleaned up browser cache, rebuilt permalinks? Please, [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/380959/edit) mentioning this information.

Comment: Hi, I added those pieces of information. Thanks.